# ¿Qué debo de cambiar al migrar wordpress de host en la base de datos?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-imagenes

Cuando estoy en un dominio temporal y lo paso a uno de producción tengo que modificar los campos `siteurl` y `home` de la tabla `wp_options` del dominio anterior al nuevo, pero normalmente las imágenes no funcionan y se quedan con la del dominio anterior,

¿saben qué otras tablas tengo que actualizar para el correcto funcionamiento?

Comment: segunda parte de la respuesta, usando wp-cli

Comment: Generalmente Wordpress guarda las imágenes dentro de la carpeta `wp-content/uploads` y dentro de `uploads` las va organizando en carpetas por año y dentro de cada año, por mes, de modo que tus imágenes de mayo de 2018 debería estar aquí: `public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/05` entonces, tendrías que trasladar el contenido completo del `uploads` local a la carpeta `uploads` en producción (web), de lo contrario, las imágenes no se verán. Este es el comportamiento por defecto de Wordpress. De todos modos, para comprobar, revisa la ruta de una  imagen cualquiera dentro de un post.

Comment: Lo que tiene que hacer es cambiar en toda la base de datos todas las coincidencias de su host anterior, esto se da porque wordpress guarda todo como rutas absolutas. Para esto hay un plugin muy útil que se llama Search & replace, lo que hace es buscar las coincidencias de su host anterior y los cambia por el nuevo para que wordpress funcione con normalidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para migrar completamente un wordpress de un dominio a otro modificando la información del dominio en todos los campos de las bases de datos donde aparece, basta con ejecutar las siguientes consultas:

```
update wp_posts set 
post_content = replace(post_content,'http://url_vieja.com', 'http://url_nueva.com') 
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

update wp_posts set 
guid = replace(guid, 'http://url_vieja.com', 'http://url_nueva.com');

update wp_options set
option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://url_vieja.com', 'http://url_nueva.com'); 

update wp_postmeta set 
meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://url_vieja.com', 'http://url_nueva.com');
```

Es un simple `replace` que detectará todas las coincidencias de `http://url_vieja.com` y las sustituirá por `http://url_nueva.com` modificando todas las rutas almacenadas.

Comment: NO entiendo que debería ir en  'home' ni en 'siteurl';

Comment: Tal cual, esos valores no se sustituyen por nada, son las claves en la tabla `option_name`, únicamente tienes que cambiar `http://url_vieja.com` por el dominio viejo y `http://url_nueva.com` por el dominio nuevo

Comment: Implementé tu solución, pero desconfiguró un valor, sin embargo, admito que fue la que más se acercó a lo que buscaba. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que hayas actualizado tus dos campos de wp_options, puedes usar el plugin de (WP Migrate DB), lo que hace es remplazar todas tus url' en la BD, de tu dominio anterior, al nuevo. Te comparto un ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]